# rails adding custom route to existing resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

in my routes.rb file I have a resource:

```
resources :authentication
```

but I also want to create a custom route, so I have the following UNDER the previous line:

```
scope :authentication do
  get 'is_signed_in', to: 'authentication#is_signed_in?'
end
```

and I ran `bin/rake routes`

and my controller has this:

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
  def is_signed_in?
    if user_signed_in?
      render :json => {"signed_in" => true, "user" => current_user}.to_json()
    else
      render :json => {"signed_in" => false}.to_json()
    end
  end
end
```

however, when I try to access this route I keep getting a 404. This is how I'm trying to access:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/authentication/is_signed_in.json"
})
```

am I missing something? do I have to do something special to allow a route with a `.json` extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `scope` here. Just add the following *before* the line with `resources :authentication`:

```
get 'authentication/is_signed_in', to: 'authentication#is_signed_in?'
```

Alternatively, and perhaps more canonically ([see the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)), you can add more action to a given resource like this:

```
resources :authentication do
  get 'is_signed_in', on: :collection
end
```

However, in this case you might need to change the name of the `is_signed_in?` method in your `AuthenticationController` to `is_signed_in` (without the `?` at the end).

Comment: so the second option creates the `resources`, and then with `do` I can assign additional optional routes?

Comment: Basically, yes. But now I saw that the `get` method within the `resources` block is incomplete. It needs to have also `on: :collection` in order to work properly. I edited my answer again.